# App.models not found in django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to populate a database with script

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print "Starting Rango population script..."
    os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'tango_with_django_project.settings')
    from rango.models import Category, Page

    populate()
```

But, when I execute the script, it says `ImportError: No module named rango.models`. Can anyone explain why is this happening?

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iMEwa.png)

Comment: It seems likely that your script isn't located in the correct folder and that it cannot locate "rango".

Comment: Post your project directory structure please

Comment: I used pycharms context menu option to run the script, and it ran without any error, and the data is populated.

Comment: Still, I'm unable to find the reason why, it's not working with terminal!

Answer (score 0):

perhaps you need to install rango py modules
with easy_install

```
sudo easy_install rango
```

Or manually:
Source code is here:

```
wget https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/r/rango/rango-0.0.2a.tar.gz#md5=7a753e4a84fbfc9dda3f267fa1c9a5c3
```

Extract archive:

```
tar xzvf rango-0.0.2a.tar.gz
```

Go to DIR and manually install it

```
sudo python setup.py install
```

This should help.